# How to reduce calls to Angular $digest-cycle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, digest

**Problem**

While the `$digest`-cycle in my app still runs quite fast, i noticed that some callbacks (which are bound in the templates for example via `ng-if`) are called way more often than i expected. This goes up to 100+ calls on a single UI-interaction (where I would generally expect something between 3 or 10 calls at most).

I would like to understand why the callbacks are called this often and possibly reduce the number of calls to prevent future performance Issues.

**What I tried**

From my understanding the described behaviour means that the `$digest`-cycle takes up to a few-hundred loops to remove all dirty-flags and make sure that all rendered nodes are up-to-date.

I simplified several callbacks to just return `true` - instead of evaluating some model-values - which had no effect on the number of `$digest` calls at all. I also checked the Performance-Tab in the Chrome-developer-Tools which only told me that the calls themselves are executed within a few ms.

For trouble-shooting i also removed several `ng-repeat` blocks and `angular-filters` throughout the application since those obviously apply several watches to be evaluated in the $digest loop. This had no impact on the number of calls to the callback-functions either.

Thus i guess i need a more sophisticated tool or method to debug the (number of) $digest calls throughout my application to even figure out where all those calls are coming from and how to reduce them.

**Questions**

Which tools and methods can I use to evaluate the performance of the $digest-loop (and especially the number of loops) in my angular-application?

How do I reduce the number of calls to callbacks which are bound in a template?

I think to answer the second question it would already be helpful to understand what can cause additional calls to `foo()` in a setup like this:

```
<div ng-if="ctrl.foo()">
    <!--<span>content</span> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Something to point out is this: in templates, if you are expecting your 'data' from the controller to not change, you can one-way bind your data to the template. So for example instead of ng-if="vm.foo" you could write ng-if="::vm.foo"

Comment: Thanks, I found this hint (and several more) by googling for $digest performance Issues. The problem for me does not seem to be the performance itself though, but rather the amount of digest-calls in general (for which i did find hardly anything since the performance of a single loop seems to be a way more common issue)

Comment: I think you may finding this calls difference when ctr.foo() get change

Comment: Like I said above, i replaced ctrl.foo() by a function that always returns `true` to make sure that the function does not depend on a model-value which is repeatedly updated.

Answer (score 0):

First thing what does actually digest cycle in angularJS?

**1.** Its process in which angular framework check for all two way binding variable changes by its own continuously.

**2.** When ever user interact and change two way binding variable then it get fire.

**3.** programmatically(in controller, service or factory) two way binding variable get changed

Above are reasons to fire digest cycle call...

Which entity are part of digest cycle?

**1.** $watch added on variables.

**2.** ngModel, ng-model iteself internally add $watch on varaible

Basically $watch function.

**What we can do to avoid $digest/avoid call to $watch?**

1. Think about variable using in UI that does this variable need to be two way binding?
   If answer is **NO** then just go for one-way bind syntax

2. Avoid use of watch function from controller, service, factory
   Then how can I watch it...

   1. RX js is right now best library which can help to overcome this issue. Its just one option.
   2. Use getter setter

      **How?**

> ```
> mymodule.controlle('ctrName', ctrClass);
>
> ctrClass {
>     constructor($scope) {
>         this.myVar1 = null;
>         this.myVar2 = null;
>     }
>
>     set myVar1(value) {
>         // either code which i want in watcher
>         // or
>         // Some function which i want to execute after value get set
>         this.afterSet();
>         return this.myVar1 = value;
>     }
>
>     afterSet() {
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Use **controllerAs** feature of angular
4. Create directives with **isolated scopes**

**About tool:**

> To **validate** angular application Batarange is good tool.